# Sum of value_counts()==1 vs nunique()?

Tags: python, pandas

Why does the following two statements return different values for a dataset?
**sum(dataframe['column'].value_counts()==1)** vs **dataframe['column'].nunique()**

Note: The column under consideration is of string type

Comment: If you can do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples then I or others can probably easily help you.

Comment: Thank you for the heads-up. I shall try posting some sample code in the questions next time onwards.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `.nunique()` function also counts `Nan` values, whereas `.value_counts()` does not.

For example,

```
df['column'] = [1, 1, 2, 3, np.nan]
print(sum(dataframe['column'].value_counts()==1))
print(dataframe['column'].nunique())
```

will give output:

```
2
3
```

You can easily remove `nan` values by:

```
dataframe['column'].nunique(dropna = True)
```

Hope this helped you :)